# Could not find In its Advanced settings, “Polls Application” from the Application menu while following official Django CMS tut

Tags: django, django-cms

```
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

#My cms_apps.py looks like this
class PollsApphook(CMSApp):
    app_name = "polls"
    name = _("Polls Application")

    def get_urls(self, page=None, language=None, **kwargs):
        return ["polls.urls"]


apphook_pool.register(PollsApphook)  # register the application
```

Now when i look into advanced settings under [Looks this way no "Polls Application" option in drop down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBYPw.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also, you should first check which version of Django CMS you use. The tutorial version is the stable version, but i guess you use 3.2.X or something. In stead of the def get_url line you should make the class look like this

```
class PollsApphook(CMSApp):
    app_name = "polls"
    name = _("Polls Application")
    urls = ["polls.urls"]
```

Comment: This is the solution to me!